# Bizarre behaviour of bash 3.2.25 printf internal comand according to LANG environ variable

Tags: bash, printf

My script contains

```
#!/bin/bash

echo before: LANG=$LANG LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC
unset LANG LC_NUMERIC
echo after: LANG=$LANG LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC

printf "%f\n" .34
```

When I run this script in RHEL 6 (bash 4.1.2), it works as expected:

```
before: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=
after: LANG= LC_NUMERIC=
0.340000
```

But when it runs in a RHEL 5 (bash 3.2.25), the `printf` seems to ignore de lack of **`LANG`** environment variable and reports an error message because it expects to find a comma (**,**) instead of a dot (**.**) as a decimal separator:

```
before: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=
after: LANG= LC_NUMERIC=
./myscript.sh: line 7: printf: .34: invalid number
0,000000
```

It works when I get rid of the LANG environment variable just before launching the script:

```
$ unset LANG
$ sh myscript.sh
LANG= LC_NUMERIC=
LANG= LC_NUMERIC=
0.340000
```

I always use `unset LANG` at the beginning of my scripts to prevent this kind of side effects; but, in this case, it seems no to work.

Is it a bug?

Thanks

Comment: `bash` 3.2.25 is *really* old and predates Shellshock, so you would be much better off upgrading to at least 3.2.57 before worrying about whether this is a bug. (FYI, if it *is* a bug, it's specific to that version or Redhat. I cannot reproduce on macOS on 3.2.57.)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem on bash 4.4.  You probably have `LC_ALL` set, `LC_ALL` is *supposed* to override `LANG`.

Setting `LC_ALL`:

```
echo before: LANG=$LANG LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC
unset LANG LC_NUMERIC
LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8
echo after: LANG=$LANG LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC

printf "%f\n" .34
```

Gives:

```
./gash.sh: line 8: printf: .34: invalid number
0,000000
```

This is only setting `LANG`:

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
echo before: LANG=$LANG LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC
unset LC_ALL LC_NUMERIC
echo after: LC_ALL=$LC_ALL LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC

printf "%f\n" .34
```

Gives:

```
before: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=
after: LC_ALL= LC_NUMERIC=
./gash.sh: línea 8: printf: .34: número inválido
0,000000
```

But **this** unsets both:

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
echo before: LANG=$LANG LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC
unset LANG LC_ALL LC_NUMERIC
echo after: LANG=$LANG LC_ALL=$LC_ALL LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC

printf "%f\n" .34
```

Gives:

```
before: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=
after: LANG= LC_ALL= LC_NUMERIC=
0.340000
```

So, unset `LANG` *and* `LC_ALL`.

Comment: I assure you that the `LC_ALL` variable is not a crux in this problem. In fact, my original script, not the reduced version I showed here,  contains `unset LANG LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_MESSAGES LC_NUMERIC LC_CTYPE`

Comment: I suggest you add `LC_ALL` to your question and redo the examples. Please don't miss out important features like that from your questions.   I won't delete my post because others might waste time on it as I have done.

Comment: I'm sorry for you but I didn't mention those **important features** because they are not important in the results of this problem. You **wongly** assumed my problem hinged on the `LC_ALL` variable; which this is not the case.

Comment: Since I could reproduce your problem with `LC_ALL`, and you had not unset it in the code you showed, it seemed a reasonable assumption.  Anyway, moving on...

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce this then the best I can do is some guesses.  This is obviously something to do with locales.  So, instead of unsetting `LC_ALL` and `LANG`, set them to `C`, e.g.   `LC_ALL=C`.  That *should* make no difference, but maybe there is some setting for the default which is different.  As I said, only a guess.

Comment: Next,  try exporting the variables, `export LC_ALL LANG`.  They might already be exported, I have no way of knowing.  The should not need that in this case, but maybe you are picking-up `/bin/printf` instead of the built-in `printf`.  `dash` and old versions of bash do not have `printf` as a builtin, so it reverts to the external program.  I know that contradicts some of the things you say, but I'm guessing.

Comment: Finally, as a last resort, run `ltrace` on your script and search for the `setlocale()` and `localeconv()` function calls which might give a hint.  By the way, `setlocale()` ole uses `LC_ALL`, not `LANG`.  If you don't know how to run `ltrace` then drop me a comment.  As I say, that's a last resort.